# How to SSl Socket.io in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, websocket, socket.io

After reading almost every questions with its suggested solution, I still don't get a secure websocket connection working.

Without SSL its working like a charm.

This is my non-secure server:

```
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const port = 8025;

const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Server is responding!");
})


const io = new Server(httpServer);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.onAny((event, args) => {
        console.log('event:', event, 'args:', args);
        io.emit(event, args);
    });

});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Socket.io server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

This is my non-secure client:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('ws://example.com:8025');


socket.on('message', (args) => {
    console.log('client args', args);
});

socket.emit('message', 'one message ' + Date.now());
```

But this fails, e.g., the connection does not work:

Server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const port = 8025;

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/spl.audio.key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/spl.audio.crt.pem'),
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("Server is responding!");
})


const io = new Server(httpsServer);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.onAny((event, args) => {
        console.log('event:', event, 'args:', args);
        io.emit(event, args);
    });

});


httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Socket.io server running at https://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

Client:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('wss://example.com:8025');


socket.on('message', (args) => {
    console.log('client args', args);
});

socket.emit('message', 'one message ' + Date.now());
```

Socket.io has version 4.6.2 and NodeJs has version 18.13.0

Comment: what is the error message? and also how are you verifying the server socket(s) at the client side?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error message. If I log the socket on the client, the connected status is false.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. In the server code the ca certificate was mandatory:

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/spl.audio.key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/spl.audio.crt.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/spl.audio.ca.pem')
};
```

I good idea was to start the client with

```
DEBUG=* node index.js
```

From there I got the error message, that the certificate was invalid.